# Is there a way to use IdentityModel for automated token manegement with HTTP Clients inside Azure Activity Functions?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, identityserver4, identitymodel

Let's say I have an `HTTPClient` configured in a custom `FunctionsStartup` class to be used inside an Azure Activity function, and I wanted that client to piggyback on `IndentityModel`'s authentication token management, is there a reliable way to do this? I tried looking for solutions such as this one:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    // Config setup code removed for brevity

    var identitySettings = _config
        .GetSection("AuthenticationConfiguration")
        .Get<AuthenticationConfiguration>();

    // Configure token management
    builder.Services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
    {
         options.Client.Clients.Add("auth", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
         {
             Address = $"{identitySettings.Url}/connect/token",
             ClientId = identitySettings.ClientId,
             ClientSecret = identitySettings.ClientSecret,
             Scope = identitySettings.Scopes[0]
         });
    });

    // Piggyback token management to HTTPClient
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IService, Service>(x =>
    {
        var settings = _config
           .GetSection("Configuration")
           .Get<Configuration>();
        x.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.Url);
    }).AddClientAccessTokenHandler("auth");
}
```

But it doesn't work because Azure function's `IServiceCollection` is different from ASP.NET Core's `IServiceCollection`.

I also looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404968/using-openidconnect-with-azurefunctions) [links](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore/issues/110) but that doesn't still answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figrued it out. You need to install [`IdentityModel`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/) and [`IdentityModel.AspNetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel.AspNetCore/) packages from NuGet as they expose the methods needed to setup automated token management.

[More info](https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/how-to-automatically-fetch-access-tokens-for-an-http-client-in-net-1fe617545c7c)